# Is there a recommended route to installing JEDI and JVCL for Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, jvcl, jedi-code-library

I see that JCL and JVCL are now in GitHub and I have previously installed them both under XE3 using the built-in installer. I've also used the XE4 'special' [posted on the Embarcadero page](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29426).

Has anyone managed to get JCL and JVCL working with XE5 yet please?

Comment: It seems to me that the pace of XE3 -> XE4 -> XE5 rapid release cycle has outstripped the Jedi team's ability to test and release new installers.  However, I'm not sure what you're asking. Did you clone the GIT repos and then run the usual install batch files? Did that work? if not, what error did you get?  I would expect Andreas or someone will eventually post a new binary to CodeCentral as well.

Comment: XE5 support has been comitted. This seems to be a non-problem.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive suggestion Warren. I will see if the installer batch works from the commit.

Comment: Thanks Warren you were right, it nearly worked but with a common include file needed. See my procedure below.

Comment: You might want to accept your self-answer. I think you waited long enough ;-)

Comment: Jedi is ridiculously overweighted (difficult to install).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution for installing the JCL and JVCL latest Project Jedi code from the GIT repository, thus to get XE5 support until binary installers are readily available. This solution may be of use to others when (say) XE6 comes along....

Using TortoiseSVN, checkout the two JEDI GIT repositories so that you have a common root folder Jedi and the two checkouts are subfolders of it 'Jcl' and 'Jvcl'. The two checkouts are:

Into Jvcl folder: "https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/trunk/jvcl"
Into Jcl folder: https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/trunk/jcl"

You should arrange for the common root folder 'jedi' to be in your program files folder, e.g. 'c:\program files (x86)'

Now checkout the JEDI.INC file which you will need for XE5 but checking out from:

"https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi"

You will see a file 'jedi.inc' in this checkout. Place it into a new folder 'jedi' in the '...jcl\source\include' folder.

Now go to the jedi\jcl folder and right-click 'install.bat' using 'Run as administrator'. After answering the prompts this should install the jcl.

Now go to the jedi\jvcl folder and right-click 'install.bat' using 'Run as administrator'. After answering the prompts this should install the jvcl too.

Comment: No need to check out the jedi.inc seperately it's included via git submodules they just need to be initialized, and updated, which the install.bat should try to do.

Comment: THanks for that Robert. I ran the INSTALL.BAT of course but it just failed with the missing jedi.inc. Did I have to get it manually I checked out using SVN (i.e without GIT)?

Comment: You should install Git and clone using Git.  The subversion sources are no longer updated. Or did you use a Subversion client to check out the git repo? Because although GitHub has that feature, that defeats the intended purpose of moving to Git; So we could check out submodules for you automagically.  So if you insist on using SVN you will have to do hacks like you did.

Comment: If you are using an actual GIT client, you can clone https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl and https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl instead of the 'trunk' versions.

Comment: You can download the latest stable build as zip file from https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/tree/JCL-Latest, then zip file containing jedi.inc from https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi , then place the jedi.inc into the proper folder as described in the answer and run install.bat